# How to get command line argument parameters in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

How to get command line argument parameters in react?

I have a react code, built on Webpack. When I ran -

```
npm run build -- --configuration=dev
```

or

```
npm run build -- --configuration=qa
```

Based on that, I wanted to get the configuration parameters as DEV or QA - builds the web packs.

The problem here - How to get the npm params configuration, in the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer thank you.

```
   process.env.npm_config_configuration
```

Comment: Any other details about this, what it means, where you found it at, or your configuration? Used this in my JS and it said that process wasn't defined